# Dependency 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.2.2.Final' not found Error when using the newest hibernate Version

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, javafx

I get an Error when i try to include the newest hibernate Version in my project. I get this error:`Dependency 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.2.2.Final' not found`
IntelliJ doesnt detect the newest Version, I only get 5.4.30.Final suggested, but that version already is end-of-life and does not support the jakarta.persistence version i want to use. What could i do here? Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>at.xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXXXX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>XXXXX</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.27</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.30.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.synedra</groupId>
            <artifactId>validatorfx</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>at.xxx/at.xxxx.Main</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the warning that i get when i run the code with jakarta.persistence:
`jakarta.persistence.spi::No valid providers found.`
followed by an exception:
`No Persistence provider for EntityManager named xxxx`
the persistence-unit-name is correct.

I tried using different versions, but 5.4.30.Final is the only one that doesnt create an error.

Comment: Where is your settings.xml pointing at? Because that dependency seems to be available in normal public repositories. Are you pointing to a internal maven repository (artifactory, nexus...)?